# QGIS explode line function fails with OSM file

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, explode

I am exporting a small extract from OSM. I load the lines(layer 1) into QGIS and apply the function `Explode lines`. I get the error:

```
Algorithm Explode lines starting...
__len__() should return >= 0 See log for more details
```

Can anybody reproduce that? Is there a workaround that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are encountering this known issue: [Bug report #10000 
Cannot use osm layers (no features?)](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/10000)

You'll have to save to a different file format before you can use the data with Processing.